# Node.JS Http Request Scope

Tags: node.js, http

I'm just getting in to Node and writing a simple HTTP load tester. I'm not sure why the following code always reports each web request time in a linear way. For example, I get back that all 10 HTTP requests took a little longer than its previous. So the console looks like this:

Sent in 0.138 seconds.

Node 0 responded in 0 s, 302 ms.

Node 1 responded in 0 s, 364 ms.

Node 4 responded in 0 s, 379 ms.

Node 3 responded in 0 s, 397 ms.

Node 2 responded in 0 s, 410 ms.

Node 6 responded in 0 s, 413 ms.

Node 5 responded in 0 s, 429 ms.

Node 8 responded in 0 s, 434 ms.

Node 7 responded in 0 s, 446 ms.

Node 9 responded in 0 s, 454 ms.

In my mind I'm thinking Node should be executing the response event as soon as one of the requests gets a response. Can anyone spot how/why I'm seeing timings like that?

Here's the code (running this from a Raspberry Pi, my Mac also reports the same linear timings):

```
var http = require('http');

var workersFinished = 0;
var workersSent = 0;
var workersErrored = 0;
var workerTimers = [];

process.stdout.write('\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f');

try
{   
    http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 5000;

    var options = {
      host: '192.168.1.88',
      port: 90,
      path: '/xampp'
    };

    var callback = function(response) {
        var buffer = '';

        response.setEncoding('utf8');

        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            buffer += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            //console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(resp.headers));
            //console.log('Received bytes: ' + buffer.length);
            //console.log('Status Code: ' + response.statusCode);
            //http.request(options, callback).end();
        });
    };

    function doRequest(id, options, callback) {

        var request = http.request(options, callback);

        request.on('response', function(r) {

            var elapsed = process.hrtime(workerTimers[id]);

            console.log('Node ' + id + ' responded in ' + elapsed[0] + ' s, ' + (elapsed[1] / 1000000).toFixed(0) + ' ms.');

            //doRequest(id, options, callback); // Send this worker off again.

            workersFinished++;
        });

        request.on('error', function(error) {
            workersErrored++;
        });

        request.end();
        workerTimers[id] = process.hrtime();
    }

    var start = process.hrtime();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        doRequest(i, options, callback);
        workersSent++;
    }

    var diff = process.hrtime(start);
    var elapsedMs = diff[1] / 1000000;
    var elapsedSeconds = diff[0];

    console.log("Sent in " + elapsedSeconds + "." + elapsedMs.toFixed(0) + " seconds.");
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
```